# What is the simplest way (or simplest library) to create a truly secure php mail() function?

Tags: php, security, email, substitution

The mail() function is bad, because it is so permissive with headers that you pretty much can't use it with any user input without subjecting yourself or others to spam.  So what is the simplest substitute that can still ensure that it's use is secure?

Ideally something that can be included in an external file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://swiftmailer.org/ seems to be the most popular PHP OO solution currently

Comment: And by "that will work" I mean: it's actually the best solution out there, a great library.